# c++ win32 console application is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

so I just installed vs2015, and I'm having issues starting a project. For my intro school programming class, we are learning with the win32 console. I started up my own project at home so I could work on my projects at home, but I'm having issues starting. Thanks in advance for any help. [Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiggQ.png)

Comment: The error message is telling you the problem.  It's giving you a filename, and saying it can't execute it.  As a first step, have you checked whether that file exists?

Comment: The file does not exist. How to I create the proper file?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620919.aspx

Comment: Hello Greg, I followed the steps but the same error pops up. How do I create the proper .exe file that the debugger needs? Thank you. EDIT: Nevermind, I fixed the issue. Thanks Afflicted!

Answer (score -1):

Your issue is annoying yet simple to fix, before I answer it you're using visual studio 2015 which means by default you would have been "given " a header file and  your main would have looked like the following.

```
#include "stdafx.h"    
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   return 0;
}
```

You can modify the main function, as in remove every thing but int main() but I would suggest not doing this.

The answer to your question is, your program will not compile because you are not using `#include "stdafx.h"`

simply put that in and your projects will work assuming you code them right...

Also after looking at your picture more closely ( next time post your code here)
I see that your only source file showing is named R4.Que? Rename it R4.cpp

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the issue. I was naming my files completely wrong. Very embarrassing... I just need to find out out to get the stdafx.h source file, since it isn't showing. I'm sure I can find the solution elsewhere. Thanks!

Comment: Or turn off precompiled headers.

Comment: @Connor H. You can try immibis suggestion as well, when you set your project up a little box pops up instead of clicking finish hit next and uncheck precompiled headers. But because you're using visual studios stdafx.h should by default be there... if it's not it could be an issue with your installation.